# Defining "templated class" functions outside of a class

Tags: c++

I have this class

```
template <class T> class dynamic_array
  {
```

and this function:

```
void dynamic_array::randorder()
  {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int *ap;
  for(ap=array;k!=array+size;++k){*k=rand();} 
  }
```

The compiler is complaining about my function  - "not having template parameters".  How do I add this in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
template <class T>
void dynamic_array<T>::randorder()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(int *ap = array; k != array + size; ++k)
  {
    *k = rand();
  }
}
```

Comment: Not intuitive...b.c. I do not use the template parameter in the function definition.

Comment: @stack.user.1: you use. It's hidden in the type of array.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
template <class T>
void dynamic_array<T>::randorder()
  {
...
  }
```

Also, keep in mind that you have to put the definition into a header file if you need to use it in different .cpp files.

I suppose `array` must be a data member of type `T`, so the following doesn't apply here.  But in general if you see that some member functions of a class template do not depend on the template parameters, it makes sense to factor them out into a non-template base class.  It reduces the size of the executable and makes your life easier.