# Need advice with error - while defining a function outside a template class

Tags: c++, class, templates

Here is this class:

```
template<typename T>
class TestClass
{
private:
    struct element
    {
        T data;
        element* ptr;

        explicit element(T val) : data(val), ptr (nullptr) {}
    };
    element entity;

public:
    T foo(int);
    void fee(const TestClass&);
    element* faa(T, bool order = true);

    explicit TestClass(T p1);
    ~TestClass() {}
};
```

while I tried defining the following function outside the class as:

```
template<typename T>
TestClass<T>::element* TestClass<T>::faa(T val, bool order)
{
    //blah blah blah
}
```

I got the following error: ([compiling on this site](https://onlinegdb.com/eqpzix3Or))

```
main.cpp:36:1: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘TestClass::element’ because ‘TestClass’ is a dependent scope
   36 | TestClass<T>::element* TestClass<T>::faa(T val, bool order)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      | typename
```

I tried searching on stack overflow - [got THIS page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014763/defining-templated-class-functions-outside-of-a-class). But I am still not understanding where is my error. Kindly advice.

Comment: [Here is a link to a more appropriate post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/631266)

Comment: Did you try doing exactly what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: Still couldn't understand - what is wrong with my syntax. Please point out.

Comment: `typename` is a keyword that you need to tell the compiler how to parse your `faa` definition properly. The compiler error says this exactly. As a side question, how exactly does one use a pointer to a private struct outside of class definition?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik > I am unable to understand - "before" part of the error message. Because there is already a 'typename T' before TestClass<T>::element

Comment: The third line of the compiler error uses the `^` character to indicate the exact position it wants to see `typename`. It's really rather helpful ;-).

Comment: @dmedine - answer to your side question - this faa function is supposed to be a private member function. Sorry, for the typo.

Comment: The line with the error should begin with `typename TestClass<T>::element`…

Comment: template<typename T>
typename TestClass<T>::element* TestClass<T>::faa(T val, bool order);
---- solved my problem - but I am unable to grasp the significance of my error/mistake of my conception!! Even after going through the dissertation mention by @AviBerger

Comment: Welcome to C++, the linked question explains it. I wouldn't call this an error or an oversight, this is just a missing bit of understanding of an arkane part of C++'s complicated syntax. After making the same error a few times one will often instinctively learn when and where to shove an extra `typename`, in the right place.